# Cypher: find a path which takes the maximum valued step each time

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to write a cypher query that finds a path between nodes a and b such that each step has the maximum timestamp value out of all available alternatives that is less than 15.

Here is my query so far, it does everything except for select the maximum possible timestamp at each step. How do I express this condition?

```
MATCH path=(a:NODE)-[rs:PARENT*]->(b:NODE)
WHERE a.name = 'SOME_VALUE' and b.name = 'SOME_OTHER_VALUE' AND ALL (r IN rs 
  WHERE r.timestamp < 15) 
RETURN path
```

This is just awful sudo code but I think it expresses what I am looking for

```
MATCH path=(a:NODE)-[rs:PARENT*]->(b:NODE)
WHERE a.name = 'SOME_VALUE' and b.name = 'SOME_OTHER_VALUE' AND ALL (r IN rs 
  WHERE r.timestamp < 15 AND r.timestamp = max(allPossibleRsForThisStep)) 
RETURN path
```

Can this kind of query be written in cypher?

Comment: what does "this-step" mean in your model? one relationship? How would you calculate that max?

Comment: Sorry by steps I mean the relationships that join each pair of nodes in the path. By maximum step I mean the PARENT relationship with the maximum timestamp value. I want the path from a to b that contains relationships with the maximum possible timestamp property < 15.

Comment: I still wonder if you should reconsider the model, and possibly that would be a good question. If your data is stored orderd you can avoid all this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be fast in cypher, it's possible to compute all maximum values first and then do what you want to do by compare the max value in a list with the current value.

Something like this (not sure if it works)

```
WITH range(1,10) as max_vals // a list with 10 values (actual values are not that important)
MATCH (a:NODE)-[rs:PARENT*..10]->(b:NODE)
WHERE a.name = 'SOME_VALUE' and b.name = 'SOME_OTHER_VALUE'
WITH a,b, 
      map(idx in range(0,size(rs)) | 
        max_vals[idx] = case when max_vals[idx]<rs[idx].timestamp then rs[idx].timestamp else max_vals[idx] end ), max_vals


MATCH path=(a)-[rs:PARENT*..10]->(b)
 AND ALL (idx in range(0,size(rs)  WHERE rs[idx].timestamp < 15 AND rs[idx].timestamp = max_vals[idx]) 
RETURN path
```

Comment: You mentioned it not being fast in cypher. Is there a better way of doing this sort of query? Basically its a constraint shortest path query that I want to execute.

Comment: I'd write a Server Extension that implements this on the lower level Java-API, if you can.

Comment: Always depends on the depth/size of your graph. If it just a few 10k nodes then cypher will be ok too.